# Erro no eclipse instalado no deepin linux

Tags: java

Meu eclipse está apresentando um erro na tela de console, apesar de rodar blz o programa. Estou usando o deepin linux 15.5 e Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

O erro:

[image: print da tela do eclipse com um simples Hello World]

Answer (score 0):

Isto não é um erro.

Como o texto em vermelho no console sugere, é um "aviso" de que encontrou uma opção java, que neste caso parece ser de utilizar uma configuração de fonte específica.

Answer (score 0):

É um warning que ocorre no deepin após a instalação do java, resolvi colocando no arquivo `/home/user/.profile` os seguintes comandos.

```
_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS"  
unset _JAVA_OPTIONS 
alias java='java "$_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS"'
```

Recarregar o .profile com o comando `source .profile`